# How to use ng-model inside ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, web

I am using ng-repeat in Angular 1.x, and I am trying to create each iteration unique ID / class / ng-model.

```
<input type="text" id="url-placeholder" placeholder="Companion URL" class="creative-url-box" ng-model="newCreative.companionUrl">
```

all this is under `ng-repeat`, and when I want to create new object, that create me the same object all the time.

I tried to add `{{$id}}` to ID and class but something went wrong.
so how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I want to create new object, that create me the same object all the time.?

```
 ng-model="newCreative.companionUrl">
```

During each iteration you are using same `model`.Thats why you getting same value.

With [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) it provide `$index` having different value in each iteration.

We can use it to create new modal instance.

```
<div ng-repeat="oneRec in arrRec">
<input type="text" id="url-placeholder"  ng-model="newCreative[$index].companionUrl">
</div>
```

Now,you have array of `newCreative` access it using index .It will create new object

Answer (score 0):

Use `$index` inside your `ng-repeat` for dynamic, Like below :

```
<input type="text" id="url-placeholder" placeholder="Companion URL" class="creative-url-box" ng-model="newCreative.companionUrl{{$index}}">
```

but, Recommended way is to use try to use `companionUrl` property of your iterator `newCreative`, it will be unique for each item of collection.

Like for example :

```
<Div ng-repeat = "newCreative in newCreativeCollection track by $index">
    <input type="text" id="url-placeholder" placeholder="Companion URL" class="creative-url-box" ng-model="newCreative.companionUrl">
</Div>
```

where your `newCreativeCollection`, should be like :

```
    $scope.newCreativeCollection  = [{
       companionUrl : '',
       //other properties
       }, 
      .. othet items
   ]
```